# How to fix pydev debugger error in Pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

Yesterday I updated my python, this caused my debugger to not function properly.

I keep getting the following error in output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)
pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints.
pydev debugger: Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connected to pydev debugger (build 222.4459.20)
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen codecs>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen zipimport>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen ntpath>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen genericpath>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen os>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen _collections_abc>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <string>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen abc>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <__array_function__ internals>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen io>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-0>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-1>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-2>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-3>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-4>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-5>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-6>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib.util>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen runpy>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-7>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-8>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-9>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <decorator-gen-10>
```

What can be done to fix it?

I Tried to freshly install Python and Pycharm. nothing really changed.

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: @Chris by using the newest version installer

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that there is a bug in Pycharm current version and What helped me fix it is to download the EAP version 2022.3. I did not receive anymore errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).